# get empty dataset result in vb.net

Tags: plsql, dataset, vb.net-2010

writing procedure in pl/sql . calling this procedure in vb.net. I want to fill the dataset with the result of pl/sql procedure. but am getting empty dataset. In pl/sql am able to see the output.in my application am using oracle.dataaccess.client dll.Help me to get the result in dataset.

```
 using  this dll
 Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client
my code



 Dim orc1 As Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection
 orc1 = New OracleConnection("Data Source=xxx;User Id=qqq;Password=123;")
 orc1.open()
Dim objcommand3 As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand

objcommand3.Connection = orc1
objcommand3.CommandText = "SMSDND.pro_mod934"
objcommand3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
Dim oraada As New OracleDataAdapter(objcommand3)
            'oraada .SelectCommand =objcommand3
Dim ods As New DataSet
oraada.Fill(ods)




procedure in pl/sql(using oracle toad)


CREATE  procedure SMSDND.pro_mod934
as
cursor c78 is 
SELECT smsdnd.phonenumbers_tbl.FLD_PHONENUMBER 
FROM smsdnd.phonenumbers_tbl
WHERE not exists (select smsdnd.smsdnd_tbl.FLD_PHONENUMBERS from smsdnd.smsdnd_tbl
where smsdnd.smsdnd_tbl.FLD_PHONENUMBERS = smsdnd.phonenumbers_tbl.FLD_PHONENUMBER and   smsdnd.smsdnd_tbl.FLD_OPSTYPE='A');
m  smsdnd.phonenumbers_tbl.FLD_PHONENUMBER %type;
BEGIN
 OPEN c78;
LOOP
 FETCH c78 INTO m;
EXIT when c78%NOTFOUND;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(''|| m);
END LOOP;
CLOSE c78;
 EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 
  raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR-  '||SQLERRM);
end;
/
```

Comment: What's the proc look like?  Are you getting any exceptions or just an empty DataSet?  When you run the proc (using the same UID/PWD in Oracle), do you get results?

Comment: wait i ll edit my quest and attach the procedure and result

Comment: @David i didnt get any exception. getting only empty dataset

Comment: @david ya i get result when i run the procedure in oracle toad